# How to identify which user/who created the Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Just wondering that whether we can able to find a Journey creator name in the Journey builder UI [from the SFMC UI].

I am aware this possible to check using the below REST endpoint.

> [Get Interaction (Journey) Audit Log](https://api.mcexperts.ninja/#150e92ea-06f3-4a72-bc59-8431cc6e02c1)

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks for rephrasing my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this information isn't present in the Journey Builder UI and has to be retrieved using the Audit Log API.

Comment: Thanks Markus for confirming on this.

Comment: thanks Markus, calling the Audit Log API is it still the only way to get it or you can via GUI now?

Comment: @eeadev Yes, this still is the case unfortunately.